# Loading script files when creating a pyinstaller exe of a Django application

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, pyinstaller

I am trying to package a django application which also contains script files(angularJS). When I create an exe , its not able to load the static files(404 error). I tried 
python manage.py collectstatic and its copying the files from the correct location.
But when I run the exe, its not able to load the files.

Theres a related question,but that solution didnt solve the problem.[Location of static files when creating a Django exe using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193073/location-of-static-files-when-creating-a-django-exe-using-pyinstaller)

My settings.py file

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/res/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "res")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Rule/res'),
)
```

My spec file:

```
added_files = [
     ('Rule\\templates\\*.html','Rule\\templates'),
     ('Rule\\migrations','Rule\\migrations'),
     ('Rule\\res\\scripts\\*.js','Rule\\res\\scripts'),
     ]
```

Its able to load the templates, but not the script files.

I am loading the script files in my html file like this:

```
{% block js %}
<script src='{% static "scripts/app.js" %}' ></script>
<script src='{% static "scripts/angular.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "scripts/angular-ui-router.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "scripts/angular-route.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src="{% static "scripts/ui-grid.min.js" %}"></script>
```

{% endblock %}

Please help me if I am missing something.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this: [Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)

In your urls.py file, you should add something like the following:

```
from django.conf import settings

from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^login$', login, name='login'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```